# Why my div can't FadeIn on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one container div and I wan't to FadeIn when scroll position on him.

I don't know why my code doesn't work. Here is link on JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/2195/

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid contact nopadding hideme" id="contact">
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div class="contacttitle">
            <hr class="hrtitle"/><h2 class="fontraleway">CONTACT US</h2><hr class="hrtitle"/>
        </div>
        <span class="subtitle">Wanna ask us something? Use the form below.</span>

        <div class="row nopadding nomargin">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                <form>  
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Name*">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email adress*">
                    <input type="subject" class="form-control" id="exampleInputSubject" placeholder="Subject">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">S U B M I T</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--Closed div mainContainer-->
</div><!--Closed div contact-->
```

CSS

```
opacity:0;
```

jQuery

```
(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

so the problem is that the bottom of the window is never greater than the bottom of the object, so you can either push the object up using a bottom margin or you could do:

`if( bottom_of_window >= bottom_of_object)`

Also you want to do `$(document).ready(function() ...` at the beginning

[Here's a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lmJiVoIuoiHGY72lhQto?p=preview)

Comment: THats working great on  your demo, but I copied your .js file in my script tag and not working, on scroll, thats working on page load not when I scroll to that div

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... i tried it in your demo and it works when i make the changes. just add the `$` before `(document).ready`, add the  `=` after the `>` and then click "Run" in the top left, then scroll to the bottom of the window and it should work

Comment: IN my case on my project, this div is on middle of page not on bottom

Comment: If it's working in the demo but not in your code, then something else in your code must be interfering. You have to try finding what that is or post more code as I cannot help without knowing anything else

Comment: I updated now plunkr and not working with other content
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ee0kLXZuV5b6CFGH4Gsc?p=preview

Comment: So a couple of things. 1, you didn't import jquery into the plunkr. 2, the `hideme` class wasn't on any of the elements in the plunkr. 3, make sure you actually trigger the scroll event by scrolling on the window. This can be done by making your browser window smaller or increasing the margin (which is what i have done in the following just to show it working). [Here's a new version](http://plnkr.co/edit/s63wj9oGv12ictTBZ0JA?p=preview)

Comment: I don't know why in my big project not working :( , I included this jquery  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js , maybe it is problem??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do some interactivity on scroll. your approach is incorrect. Try this [way](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/2200/).

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
 var bottom_of_object = $(".hideme").offset().top;
 if (scroll > bottom_of_object) {
    hide();
 }
});

function hide() {
 $('.hideme').animate({
    opacity: '1'
  }, 2000);
}
```

You can use transition in css and only add class in  javascript. That will be performing better.

Comment: THats working great on your demo, but I copied your .js file in my script tag and not working, on scroll, thats working on page load not when I scroll to that div

Comment: You should add jQuery in your page then add the class `hideme` in one that you want to hide. Checkout this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UAimcBYXjSvxdbaOK8ia?p=preview)